# How to run Tomcat on Mac as external tool for Intellj Idea

Tags: macos, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8, macos-sierra

I'm setting up my JavaEE environment with IntelliJ Idea 2016.3.5 at my Mac, Sierra. My Tomcat live at /usr/local/3th party app/appache-tomcat-8.0.36./. I'm not able to use another Tomcat, e.g. somewhere at /User folder, where I deploy the webapp.

> Error running Tomcat: Cannot run program "/usr/local/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/" (in directory "/usr/local/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin"): error=13, Permission denied

My question:
How can I get the access to this Tomcat folder when I set the path to tool settings for IntelliJ's external tool?

Comment: You should specify the startup script which has `+x` permission, not a directory (`/usr/local/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/startup.sh`)

Answer (score -1):

You must ensure that you are able to read your tomcat directory.

Open terminal and locate your tomcat directory.  Run this command:

*chmod -R 777 usr/local/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/*

That should allow you to run the tomcat server as an external tool in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Changing permissions for all files is really a bad idea. Just add executable permissions to executable programs.